# My daughter is asked to perform in front of adults constantly

Tags: toddler, education

My daughter is 1.5 years old and when she learns something new or does something memorable, her mother and grand parents (my in-laws) will be amused and keep asking her to do it again in front other adults.

I do not really like this as this may slowly train my daughter into pleasing other adults on purpose.

Am I worried too much?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the emphasis is on the adults being proud of her, and no one tries to cajole her if she clearly does not want to do something, then I think it should be fine.  Toddlers love games where they can do something and get a strong positive response from their parents or other adults they know.  Keep things upbeat, and make it clear to your daughter that was she is doing is *awesome!*  If she is resistant, or hesitant, or tired of the activity though, don't press her; you don't want to take the fun out of a good game.